# how can i update these css classes to generate a blue box behind the first letter of a word?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to customize a titles in a Microsoft share point portal and found these 4 css classes to control the title design:

```
   .ms-WPTitle {font-weight: bold; font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #003399; padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 7px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; font-size: 8pt; }
   .ms-WPTitle A:link, .ms-WPTitle A:visited { color:#003399; text-decoration:none; cursor:hand; }
   .ms-WPTitle A:hover { color:red; text-decoration:underline; cursor:hand; }
   .ms-toolbar { font-family: verdana; font-size: .68em; text-decoration: none; color: #003399; }
```

**What updates to the above classes do i need to make the visual work as required?**

here is the problem i am trying to solve in IE 6 and IE 7 the blue square around the first letter is not working in IE. MY css used is:

```
<style>
      .FirstLetter:first-letter{font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold;color:White; background:Blue; border:1px black solid; padding-top:8px; padding-left:8px; padding-bottom:3px;}
      .Spaced{letter-spacing: 5px;font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold;}
      </style>

<div class="FirstLetter Spaced headerFont">
Executive Summary
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?  The screen shot you posted shows a blue box around the first letter in IE 7.  Do you mean that it doesn't look the same as Firefox?

Comment: the blue box needs to extend above by 10 px and to the left by 10 px. these settings dont get applied. see how anemic it looks on the left in IE?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the wrong amount of `padding` on the top and bottom of the first letter, I experimentally found that you should just increase the amount for IE6/7.

To make it display at all in IE6, you have to put a space in like this:

```
.FirstLetter:first-letter{
```

to this:

```
.FirstLetter:first-letter {
```

[**I shit you not.**](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/pseudocss.html#fltsyntax)

So, complete code which makes it look correct everywhere, as far as I can tell:

[***Live Demo***](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8NZFQ/show/light/) ([see code](http://jsfiddle.net/8NZFQ/))

**CSS:**

```
.FirstLetter:first-letter {font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold;color:White; background:Blue; border:1px black solid; padding-top:8px; padding-left:8px; padding-bottom:3px;}
                       /*^ important space!*/
.Spaced{letter-spacing: 5px;font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="FirstLetter Spaced headerFont">
Executive Summary
</div>
```

**Bonus CSS for IE <8:**

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style>
.FirstLetter:first-letter {padding-top:12px; padding-bottom:7px}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: nice answer and i've never seen js fiddle before. awesome tool.

Comment: you are a god amongst men. testing now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to apply rules to JUST the first letter, but you could try breaking the word apart and putting the first letter in its own div:

```
<div class="css-for-all-letters">
  <div class="css-for-first-letter" style="float:left;">E</div>
  <div class="css-for-the-other-letters" style="float:left;">xecutive Summary</div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

To be honest though, this could be VERY annoying if you had to swap the text (in internationalization for example).  So I would keep that in mind before you tried this.

Comment: whenever you float the div, it essentially turns it into an inline element (like a span tag).  Clearing it ensures that the float property isn't accidentally passed on to other elements (google ie float bug).  The reason I always float a div instead of just using spans is because if - for some reason in the future - you started using a js library, sometimes html generated by js libs will create a div and you could accidentally try to insert divs inside a span, which could cause rendering issues.

Comment: if you're sure you're never ever going to put anything else inside the elements but the letters of your word, you could use two span tags instead of the three div tags like <div class="css-for-all-letters">
  <span class="css-for-first-letter">E</span>
  <span class="css-for-the-other-letters">xecutive Summary</span>
</div>

Comment: i am lookign to find out what the css commands i need to add to those classes you showed to get the desired results in IE6

Comment: do whichever works for you; but i would investigate @thirtydot's answer before mine.  it seems to be much closer to what you were originally trying to accomplish.